# How to keep "Show in content area" when form is open by menuitem from code?

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

On few places in our application we open ListPage in content area. On the address line there is something like "Company/Module/Folder". On that listpages are menuitems which calls class which create menuitem and open the new ListPage form like:

```
Args args = new Args();
str param = 'Something';
MenuFunction openProjects = new MenuFunction('ListPageName',MenuItemType::Display);

args.parm(param);
openProjects.run(args);
```

When it called like that the address degenerate to "Company/"

Normally the display of that path depends on property "IsDisplayedInContentArea=Yes" on menu but I do not know how to set this in code.

How to keep the location (at least when the same ListPage is just reopen with different parameters)?

I am using Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012R2.

Comment: I need to create MenuItem instead of MenuFunction and set MenuItem.isDisplayedInContentArea https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/menuitem.isdisplayedincontentarea.aspx Or get the menuitem object from menufunction but do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when the menuitem which is not in any menu is used. So the solution is use menuitem which exist somewhere in the menu.

I also see this behavior when the callers args are used instead of creating new Args() like:

```
public static void main (Args _args) {
MenuFunction openProjects = new MenuFunction('ListPageName',MenuItemType::Display);
_args.param('Something');
openProjects.run(_args);
}
```